# What's the difference between "Not Completely True" and "Completely Not True"?

Tags: word-order, logic

From what I understand, <del>in second order propositional logic, ∀¬x and ¬∀x are equivalent statements.</del> Apparently these are not equal.   ¬∀x ≡ ∃¬x

However, rendered into the English language, consider the following case study:

```
Statement: All human beings have appendixes.  

Response 1: That's not completely true.
Response 2: That's completely not true.
```

In `Response 1`, the implication seems to be that the responder knows about appendectomy, and that some people have had their appendix removed.  In `Response 2`, the implication seems stronger than that, and while the motivation for such an expression is likely more for emphasis than pure logic, the implication seems be that `No human beings have appendixes`, which is obviously not true.

So with all due haste, the question: Which one of these is the correct word choice and why? Perhaps there are logicians in the audience that can enlighten us with specific reasoning.

Comment: In English, people [almost never say](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=completely+not+true%2C+completely+untrue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) "completely not true". They do say "completely untrue".

Comment: I don't agree with the assertion that Response 2 implies "No humans have appendices." Instead, it strongly asserts that the initial statement is untrue (which doesn't necessarily imply that the opposite statement _is_ true). English isn't Boolean.

Comment: First, it's **Propositional** Logic, not _prepositional_. Second, this is not necessarily (or even preferably) second order quantified logic; second order logic is inconsistent, whereas first order is consistent. Third, **∀¬x** and **¬∀x** are not equivalent; see [De Morgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) (p.13 on the link).

Comment: @J.R. Yes, it's likely more for emphasis.  However, the question is to what degree are the two statements different, and why?

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you know of a resource that lists a truth table for second order logic? In effect, you're referring to this statement, correct?:  `¬(∀x) φ(x) ≡ (∃x) ¬φ(x)`

Comment: There will certainly be situations where ∀¬x and ¬∀x turn out to select exactly the same set of truth values, for some x. But in general truth tables don't work well in second-order logic; though human language doesn't care and goes on being happily underspecified, ambiguous, and contradictory anyway.

Comment: OK, I didn't see the edit. Now it's confusing; ¬∀x ≡ ∃¬x is correct. Are you asking about English or about logic?

Comment: @JohnLawler The rendering of the two statements and how that affects the truth of `Response 1` and `Response 2`.

Comment: Truth is a logical concept, whereas the statements are English; how are they connected? And what do you mean by "rendering"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reponse 1 means that what has been said is only partially true. Response 2 means that what has been said is untrue. In practice, the thought expressed in Response 2 is more likely to occur as something like ‘That’s not true at all.’

Answer (score 0):

Response 1 suggests that there's more to add to the original statement, while response 2 suggests there's nothing else to add to the statement!

Comment: That may be true, but it's not helpful in answering the OP's question.